# TBB with fixed number of threads for one task, and default for others

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I want to execute a for-loop in parallel (using TBB) over a set of blocks, where each block will be processed using a user-supplied function. Normally, I would do this using `tbb::parallel_for()`. For various reasons, I want to be able to limit the number of threads processing the blocks to a prescribed number, call it `j`. Normally, I would do this using `tbb::task_scheduler_init(j)`.

However, I would like the user to have the option to use TBB and, specifically, let the user-supplied function use however many cores remain. So I think `tbb::task_scheduler_init()` is out. The only solution I can see is to let the user call `tbb::task_scheduler_init()` (or ignore it all together), and just spin `j` instances of `tbb::tbb_thread` on my own in a normal for-loop. Am I missing anything? Is there a more natural way to do this in TBB? Is there some kind of a hierarchical version of `tbb::task_scheduler_init()`?

Comment: I'd change the title like: TBB with fixed number of threads for one task, and default for others

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Done. Although, I guess in my case the "others" are subtasks of the first task (parallel for-loop).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are few natural ways to limit concurrency of a certain algorithm while keep the rest as is.

1. Create separate thread and initialize it for the limited concurrency using `tbb::task_scheduler_init` as you described. Since the master threads are isolated, it will not affect main and other threads. So, you can start the parallel_for from inside of that special limited thread.
2. Use `tbb::parallel_pipeline` instead of parallel_for and specify the number of tokens = j in order to limit the number of concurrently processing tasks.
3. Use `tbb::task_arena` (was a preview feature till TBB 4.3) to do the same as described in (1) but without additional master thread since the work can be put into isolated concurrency context (arena) using just its API

Example of (3):

```
tbb::task_arena limited_arena(j);
limited_arena.execute([]{ tbb::parallel_for(...); });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anton. This is very helpful. I need to read up on the last two options.